# Spring Cloud Data Flow filter starter app not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have enhanced SCDF application starter (**Filter** processor)  adding just a library and rebuilt it.
After the enhancement the **expression** property does not work at all.
Could you please elaborate what we might have missed?
For the modification we followed the following:

[How to patch spring cloud data flow starter application (add oracle driver to jdbc-source app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263748/how-to-patch-spring-cloud-data-flow-starter-application-add-oracle-driver-to-jd)

Comment: More precisely I have rebuilt both filter-function and filter-processor before generating the binder app.

Comment: What is a symptom that you indicate it does not work?

Comment: Basically it does nothing. It seems that "expression" functionality is not enabled at all without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: Artem , do u think I might missing something during the build phase of filter app?

Comment: Maybe you can share with us what you have so far in the end and we can run your solution to reproduce?

Comment: Artem, you can use the following public repo to pull the modified filter app. Please try to apply expression in order to test. Thanks. 
   https://gallery.ecr.aws/u8w2v2j0/public/filter-rs2

Comment: @ArtemBilan Did u get the chance to look at that image?

Comment: Sorry, I did not. Now I have looked into that and I cannot understand what is that AWS stuff. Why cannot you share a GH repo with just source code and instructions what to do to reproduce?

Comment: Either way, I think you are missing this stuff to do on your custom artifact: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/applications/application-metadata/#creating-metadata-artifacts

Comment: Whenever I've seen it do nothing, is when spring.cloud.function.definition doesn't match any defined beans.  Easy to check by adding a log message when the bean is initialize.